# How to reproduce eclipse's run arguments in java code?

Tags: java

Assume I have a java program that I am not allowed to change, but I need to use it in my own java program and interact with its classes. This program uses many features that I am not familiar with like reflection API, singleton pattern, Guice, injector, ....

The only input I am able to give it is via run configuration with something like (Run > Run Configuration > Arguments):

```
 aFullClassName paramName0=value0 paramName1=value1 ...
```

None of the parameters get any other value in the entire program. So I need to pass these values when I call the main of this program.

Now I want to create an object of one of its classes that invokes main method, I came up with following code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void run(){
        sim.main(new String[]
             { 


           //My question is here, how should I list the arguments?

     });
    }
}).start();
```

but I am not sure how can I list the arguments, should I include their parameter name as well? Like `"seed=125"`?

Comment: How would it look like if you were to call this program from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact way of reproducing programatically a JVM invocation from a command-line (like Eclipse's RUN wizard) in the form of `aFullClassName paramName0=value0 paramName1=value1 ...` is like this:

```
String[] arguments={"paramName0=value0", "paramName1=value1"};
aFullClassName.main(arguments);
```

And also you'll have to take care of possible exceptions thrown by the `main` method. You'll know by the errors reported by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that. Can `aFullClassName`  be an object of that class? I am trying to deal with the same object in both programs.

Comment: Though it may be, it would be useless, for `main` is a _static_ method: It is never executed on a certain instance of a class, but on the class itself. That's the reason the compiler warns you not to call a static method on an instance reference: You'd might have the wrong idea that invoking it on different instances would produce different results.

Comment: Thank you @Little Santi  for clarification, you are right :)